# Relative URL for AJAX call - how to make it work for all files in site via an include?

Tags: jquery

I'm using includes to insert the same jQuery code into all pages of my site. The problem is when doing an AJAX call, setting a relative link for the URL only works for some pages, not all.

I can't set the AJAX URL from site root because the URL changes based on product/release version.

I don't want to have to update the include file at every release in order to make sure it has the correct absolute URL.

The URL syntax is: `<domain>/<product>/<version>/<content>`

The `<content>` directory contains html pages as well as sub-directories with more pages.

One URL might be `<domain>/<product>/<version>/topics/green/goingGreen.html` and another might be `<domain>/<product>/<version>/lists.html`. Obviously, a relative URL for the AJAX call won't work for both pages.

How do I make the AJAX call work for all files in the site via includes, without using an absolute link?

```
ajax: {
    url: '<absolute link> #' + $(this).text().toLowerCase(),
    loading: false,
    success: function (elems) {
        if (elems.length) {
            this.set('content.text', elems);
            var $elems = $(elems);
        } else {
            this.destroy();
        }

    }
}
```

If you're curious, I'm using qTip to pull content from a specific file to pop-up when a user hovers over specific terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clip your current URL to the number of slashes you want:

For example,

```
var relpath = window.location.pathname.match(/^(\/[^\/]*){3}/)[0];
```

Will return the first three portions of your your URL (/domain/product/version). Replace the `{3}` with any other number you want to get a different number of levels into your current path. Use this to form your AJAX URL as an absolute path (that is still sensitive to your current relative position).